# Why are there separate investigations into Trump's alleged collusion with Russia?

Tags: united-states, mueller-investigation, special-prosecutor

It seems to me as if there are two separate and concurrent investigations into Trump's (and his presidential campaign team's) alleged collusion with Russia. One is run by the Senate Intelligence Committee while the other is being run by a special counsel appointed by the Justice Department.

Should one investigation supersede the other? Why are there two separate investigations taking place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60326/discussion-between-scfi-and-jalynn2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, both investigations are looking into different things.

The [Justice Department's investigation](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/live/2017/may/17/donald-trump-russia-james-comey-flynn-live) which is led by special counsel Robert Mueller, the former FBI director, is investigating "any links and/or coordination between the Russian government and individuals associated with the campaign of President Donald Trump".

As for the [House and Senate Intelligence Committees' investigations](http://www.latimes.com/nation/la-na-russia-hearings-20170605-story.html), they are mainly looking into Russia’s attempts to influence the 2016 election and Trump campaign’s alleged ties to Russia and possible collusion.

The main difference is the outcomes of these investigations. The Justice Department is able to recommend criminal charges should they discover any wrongdoings while the Senate & House can initiate impeachment proceedings.

Comment: So is it all of trumps campaign staff or just certain individuals? Is Sessions under investigation?

Comment: @SCFi He's [apparently "under scrutiny"](http://www.cnn.com/2017/05/24/politics/jeff-sessions-russian-officials-meetings/index.html) but it's unclear who's under investigation as they don't usually publicly confirm who they're looking into.